# No such module 'FirebaseDatabase'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing iOS app with Swift 3 with Firebase database.

My Podfile:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
end
```

I run `pod install`, which installs the pods.

I created a class:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase // Error: no such module 'FirebaseDatabase'

class MyDatabase {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ...
}
```

But I get compiler error `no such module 'FirebaseDatabase'`, why?

Comment: Is your app called "MyApp" ?

Comment: Double check that your are opening the `*.xcworkspace` file (and not the Xcode project file).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just try this , Make sure to Update all pods and secondly we don't need to explicitly `import FirebaseDatabase` , Just write `import Firebase` and you are done

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class myDatabase {
    var DbReference = DatabaseReference()
}
```

My podFile

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

Comment: I did everything you mentioned, I get `use of unresolved identifier 'DatabaseReference'`

Comment: Did you Tried Clean (window+shift+k) and close project , Reopen and Build (window+b)

Comment: I am adding firebase without cocoapods and getting same error, Can you please let me know what needs to be done. Please help

Answer (score 3):

Build the project.

The project needs to be built once for modules that come from CocoaPods to get installed into Xcode's ModuleCache (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/) and be available for the editor's syntax checking.

Answer (score 3):

As per previous comment please check the above whether you are using:

1. `.xcworkspace` or not
2. Check your target name
3. Uninstall all pod and update your pod repo and than re install Pod

Answer (score 0):

As the previous comments, make sure to check that your **target name** is exactly the same as in Xcode project settings, make sure to work in the generated **.xcworkspace** and what also helps is to Clean your project. **Command + Shift + K**

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this step.
In your AppDelegate first import Firebase, then add the below code
[image]

Comment: This is a necessary runtime step as well. But he got a buildtime error, so he needs to look elsewhere ;)