# CalendarKit usage issue 'pod frameworks' and 'no such module' in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, calendarkit

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

It is a new project file with just this code and I try to build it.

From: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/CalendarKit/0.1.7/

Image Pods red :

[image]

```
import UIKit
import CalendarKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, DayViewDelegate, EventDataSource {

var calendario: DayView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    calendario = DayView(frame: self.view.frame)
    calendario.delegate = self
    calendario.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(calendario)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func dayViewDidSelectEventView(_ eventView: EventView) {

}

func dayViewDidLongPressEventView(_ eventView: EventView) {

}

func dayViewDidLongPressTimelineAtHour(_ hour: Int) {

}

func dayView(dayView: DayView, willMoveTo date: Date) {

}

func dayView(dayView: DayView, didMoveTo date: Date) {

}

func eventsForDate(_ date: Date) -> [EventDescriptor] {
    return []
}

}
```

Comment: did you installed `CalendarKit` by `pod install`

Comment: After install are you open AppName.workspace or AppName.xcodeproj? Which one you opened?. Clean build folder, close Xcode and unit. If not solved - delete derived data, clean build folder and run it.

Comment: yes I installed by pod install and then opened it via terminal command. Yes I opened  the .xcworkspace

Comment: Try building. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46656934/556617